# Can't create table in database with db_owner role (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have database in SQL Server 2012 SP2 Enterprise. I created new SQL Login and mapped to X database with `db_owner` role. Now I can't create table on this database. When I run simple create table script I got below error.

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'INVENTORY_TEST'.

There is no database or server trigger. I did not find any SQL Server bug related to this problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The problem solved. In the Database options - Permissions tab public Database role was added and it was Deny permission for Create database option. After I removed Deny permissions it is OK now. User can create table.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run something similar to this to create your login and user: -

```
use master;

create login Test_Login with password = 'o6aWkNWHUzfUEDmcR*!R';

use INVENTORY_TEST;

create user Test_User for login Test_Login;

exec sp_addrolemember db_owner,Test_User;
```

Then to test, this should run without error: -

```
use INVENTORY_TEST;

execute as Login = 'Test_Login'

create table dbo.t(i int)

revert
```

Also, this should return 1 if you have configured the user to be a member of the db_owner role correctly: -

```
use INVENTORY_TEST;

select IS_ROLEMEMBER('db_owner','Test_User');
```

A last point is members of db_owner can drop your database. It is usually good practice to grant the minimum permissions a user requires to perform their role and nothing more.

Comment: Below query returned 1.

Comment: I use SSMS to create Login and map to database.