# Error 297, Severity 19 trying to create new table as sysadmin

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2017, errors

I am completely scratching my head right now. I have two database instances that I am trying to add a table to, and both give me the same error:

`The user does not have permission to perform this action.`

and I have triple checked the permissions, I am on a sysadmin account. Running the following query to see what create permissions I have yields the following:

```
SELECT SYSTEM_USER

-- Now get the permissions assigned to you by the server administrator 
use tempDB 
GO 

;with getPermissions as ( SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE') ) 
select permission_name from getPermissions 
where permission_name like 'create%' 
GO
```

[image]

I have also tried creating another login with sysadmin privileges to no avail. Any ideas?

Error log picture below:

[image]

```
USE [db_test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table](
    [a] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [b] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [c] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
    [d] [bit] NULL,
    [e] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [f] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [g] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [h] [int] NULL,
    [i] [int] NULL,
    [j] [int] NULL,
    [k] [int] NULL,
    [l] [int] NULL,
    [m] [int] NULL,
    [n] [int] NULL,
    [o] [int] NULL,
    [p] [int] NULL,
    [q] [int] NULL,
    [r] [int] NULL,
    [s] [int] NULL,
    [t] [int] NULL,
    [u] [int] NULL,
    [v] [int] NULL,
    [w] [int] NULL,
    [x] [int] NULL,
    [y] [int] NULL,
    [z] [int] NULL,
    [aa] [int] NULL,
    [ab] [int] NULL,
    [ac] [int] NULL,
    [ad] [int] NULL,
    [ae] [int] NULL,
    [af] [int] NULL,
    [ag] [int] NULL,
    [ah] [int] NULL,
    [ai] [int] NULL,
    [aj] [int] NULL,
    [ak] [int] NULL,
    [al] [int] NULL,
    [am] [int] NULL,
    [an] [int] NULL,
    [ao] [int] NULL,
    [ap] [int] NULL,
    [aq] [int] NULL,
    [ar] [int] NULL,
    [as] [int] NULL,
    [at] [int] NULL,
    [au] [int] NULL,
    [av] [int] NULL,
    [aw] [int] NULL,
    [ax] [int] NULL,
    [ay] [int] NULL,
    [az] [int] NULL,
    [ba] [int] NULL,
    [bb] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [bc] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [bd] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [be] [varchar](12) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
    [A] ASC
 ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Table] ([a], [b], [c], [d], [e], [f], [g], [h], [i], [j], [k], [l],
                      [m], [n], [o], [p], [q], [r], [s], [t], [u], [v], [w], [x],
                      [y], [z], [aa], [ab], [ac], [ad], [ae], [af], [ag], [ah],
                      [ai], [aj], [ak], [al], [am], [an], [ao], [ap], [aq], [ar],
                      [as], [at], [au], [av], [aw], [ax], [ay], [trkCusT4SA], [az],
                      [ba], [bb], [bc], [bd])
              VALUES (36, N'City', CAST(2.500 AS Decimal(18, 3)), 1, N'SSS', N'CTY',
                      N'http://google.com', 200, -4, 6400, 6700, 150, 450, 6400,
                      6700, 1400, 1800, 3400, 3800, 8000, 8400, 10100, 10500, 850,
                      2430, 2880, 4460, 7480, 9060, 9540, 11070, 6400, 6700, 150,
                      450, 6400, 6700, 1400, 1800, 3400, 3800, 8000, 8400, 10100,
                      10500, 850, 2430, 2880, 4460, 7480, 9060, 9540, 11070, NULL,
                      NULL, NULL, NULL)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tracks] ADD  CONSTRAINT [IX_Table] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [A] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Running `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats`

Yields the following result:

[image]

Comment: What does `select user_name()` return?  If it's not `dbo` you're not a sysadmin.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Hi David, it returns `dbo`

Comment: is there any user at all on the database that can create a table? maybe privileged user that is not a sysadmin or db_owner. Is the create table the only thing throwing the error?

Comment: @Ronaldo no other users have high enough privilege. And yes it seems that create or alter table throws the error. I attempted to create another login with the necessary privileges and had the same issue.

Comment: is database read-only?

Comment: @MBuschi the database is not read only, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @MaxB Can you please post the _exact_ and _complete_ error message(s)? It's possible that you are getting an error from something else, like a DDL trigger, and not from the `CREATE TABLE` statement itself. Also, can you please post the exact `CREATE` statement that you are trying to execute? It's possible that this is just a wild goose chase at the moment.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I can not provide the exact create statement unfortunately... company policy and all.. Question updated with error message

Comment: @MaxB Thanks for providing more info. However, that's still not the _complete_ error. It's only the second part. What shows in SSMS? No screen shot is needed (even the error log image can be removed), just the full text from what appears to be error 297. As for the create statement, I understand about company policy, but it's fine to redact/change column names so that you aren't really giving anything away.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky that error message just says `Error: 297, Severity: 19, State: -1.`. Will update question with the query

Comment: What edition of SQL Server? Standard, Enterprise, Express, Express LocalDB? And are you actually in `[tempdb]` when executing the `CREATE  TABLE`, or what DB are you in?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Sql Server 2017 Standard. The DB I am in when executing the query is my db that I wish to alter. Am able to run this query on several other identical instances of this exact database just fine. Just one local instance giving me the headache.

Comment: @MaxB Ok, I assume that the error happens with the `CREATE` statement? If so, can you do: `CREATE TABLE dbo.[_test] ([Col1] INT);`? In either case, do any other tables currently exist in this DB? If so, are you able to add any rows to any of them?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I am unable to create a table using that query. I am able to edit tables using SSMS and also add rows.

Comment: @MaxB Can you create a View and/or Function, anything? Do you have a system policy that cancels `CREATE TABLE` statements?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky just tested this and am unable to create anything. I get the same error.

Comment: @MaxB 1) Can you create a temp table in that problem database? `CREATE TABLE #Bob (Col1 INT);`? and 2) can you create tables in other DBs on that problem instance? `USE [tempdb]; CREATE TABLE dbo.Bob2 (Col1 INT);`?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I can not create any tables in the problem database, but I can create a new database and populate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119665/discussion-between-solomon-rutzky-and-maxb).

Comment: @MaxB - did you get this resolved?

Comment: @HannahVernon Unfortunately no, it is still an issue

Answer (score 4):

This is not likely a permissions issue, at least not the type of permission you are thinking of. Typical permissions errors show up as follows:

```
Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line XXXXX
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'tempdb'.
```

Now that we have a more complete error message, we can see that indicates a "severity" of 19.

According to Microsoft SQL Server documentation:

> **Severity**         **Meaning**
>
> ---
>
> 17-19          Indicate software errors that cannot be corrected by the user. Inform your system administrator of the problem.
> 19               Indicates that a nonconfigurable Database Engine limit has been exceeded and the current batch process has been terminated. Error messages with a severity level of 19 or higher stop the execution of the current batch. Severity level 19 errors are rare and must be corrected by the system administrator or your primary support provider. Contact your system administrator when a message with a severity level 19 is raised. Error messages with a severity level from 19 through 25 are written to the error log.

This sounds more like (hypothetically) using SQL Server Express and reaching the 10 GB DB limit (even a `CREATE TABLE` statement needs to add meta data) than it does a permissions problem.

With more info it will hopefully be possible to narrow down the specific source of this. Here is what testing has shown so far:

- database is *not* read-only
- user = `dbo`
- able to run statements in question on several other identical instances of this exact database just fine. Just one local instance giving the error
- unable to create a table using `CREATE TABLE dbo.[_test] ([Col1] INT);`. but able to edit tables using SSMS and also add rows
- unable to create anything, not just Tables (View / Function / etc). get the same error.
- The size of the database is 5008.00 MB and space available is 114.16 MB
- able to create a temp table while in the problem DB: `USE [problem_db]; CREATE TABLE #Bob (Col1 INT);`
- able to create a real table in `tempdb`: `USE [tempdb]; CREATE TABLE dbo.Bob2 (Col1 INT);`
- `DBCC TRACESTATUS(-1);` shows no trace flags in use
- Compatibility mode is SQL Server 2014 (120), but have also tried 2017 (140)
- able to create a schema in the problem DB: `CREATE SCHEMA [_DeleteMe];`
- UNable to create a table in the new schema: `CREATE TABLE [_DeleteMe].[_test] ([Col1] INT);`
- Owner SID did not match between `sys.databases` and `dbo` user in the problem DB, but that has been fixed and still not able to create a table
- `TRUSTWORTHY` is `OFF`, but also `OFF` on instance where this DB is just fine

Here are some places to check for things can cancel submitted operations:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.triggers;
SELECT DB_NAME(ts.[database_id]) AS [Database],
       OBJECT_NAME(ts.[object_id], ts.[database_id]) AS [Trigger],
       OBJECT_DEFINITION(ts.[object_id]) AS [Definition],
       *
FROM   sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats ts;

SELECT * FROM sys.database_audit_specifications;
SELECT * FROM sys.database_audit_specification_details;

SELECT * FROM sys.security_policies;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question/answer here regarding SQL Server: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82367/123612

> The problem solved. In the Database options - Permissions tab public
> Database role was added and it was Deny permission for Create database
> option. After I removed Deny permissions it is OK now. User can create
> table.

Edit: While this may seem obvious, have you tried right-clicking on SQL Studio and running as administrator?

Comment: Unfortunately that was not the case, and yup I have been running SSMS as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to login with `sa` and try to create the table?

[sa Login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/principals-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#sa-login) doc says:

> The sa login has all permissions on the server and cannot be limited.

The [DENY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/deny-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) doc says:

> DENY takes precedence over all permissions, except that DENY does not
> apply to object owners or members of the sysadmin fixed server role.
> **Security Note** Members of the sysadmin fixed server role and object
> owners cannot be denied permissions."

Also, I created a user with no privileges on a database and tried to create a table and the error message was different from yours:

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 
> CREATE TABLE permission denied in
> database 'Lab'.

So, it's possible the problem is not the lack of permission, but something else like a file not being able to grow to accommodate the new table or some other problem (do you see any error on the log?).

---

In addition to [Solomon Rutzky](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/30859/solomon-rutzky)'s findings:

- There's no error message on event viewer related to this problem;
- `DBCC CHECKDB` returns 0 allocation or consistency errors;
- Generating *schema only* scripts of the database and then creating a test database
  of identical schema allowed to create tables, etc.;
- A restored backup of the problematic database on a different server
  keeps the problem.

Comment: I have been using the `sa` account do debug this actually. And what I am actually trying to do is drop a table, modify it, then reinsert it. The drop table portion of the query executes fine, but then it fails when trying to re-insert it. I'll comb through the error logs and see if anything sticks out to me.

Comment: @MaxB now that you have found another error on SQL Server log, can you check Windows log to see if there's anything there too?

Comment: Looking at my event viewer I do not see anything related to this unfortunately.

Comment: @MaxB you said you're unable to create anything, does that include a new database on that instance? Because if you can't create a new database, your problem is at the instance level, but if you can't only create objects on that specific database, the problem is at the database level.

Comment: I am able to create a new database on the server and add tables to it, so it must be a database specific issue

Comment: @MaxB what's the compatibility level of that database? Can you run a DBCC CHECKDB on that database?

Comment: `SQL Server 2014 (120)` compatibility level and DBCC CHECKDB returns 0 allocation or consistency errors

Comment: @MaxB Can you try using compatibility level 140 (since your instance is SQL Server 2017). One good thing to do now is to take a backup of that database for you're probably gonna start to mess with configurations and options of the database looking for the culprit.

Comment: Just gave this a shot and it didn't seem to help unfortunately

Comment: @MaxB you said you can create a new database and it works fine, if you `right click the problematic database > tasks > generate scripts` and use the advanced option to generate *schema only* scripts and create another database with that script, does the problem still happen on the new database? If yes, you just have to look for some weird option on the script. You don't have to check the whole script, just the relevant blocks at the beginning for database, users, roles...

Comment: generating a script of the database and then creating a test database of identical schema allows me to create tables etc.

Comment: I also tried restoring this database instance from a backup of an identical database on another server and the issue persists.

Comment: Ronaldo (and @MaxB ): good idea to script out the DB objects and recreate in a new DB on that same instance! and good to check `DBCC CHECKDB`. I had him check for trace flags (none in use) and creating a Schema in the problem DB (it worked, but still can't create objects in the new Schema).

Comment: @MaxB I'm really curious about the reason of the problem, meanwhile, in order for you to keep working on a healthy database I thought of a workaround (if you can afford some downtime on the database): generate the scripts of the database, recreate it, change the original database name and import data to the new one. This way you can fix production and keep the original database to keep looking for the culprit while everything is working.